# Search for a number in each line of a string in ksh and nawk

Tags: string, parsing, awk, ksh, nawk

The input file:

```
vnic10
e1000g1
e1000g2
vnic10
blablabla888blablablabla999blabla
```

Output needed:(Only the numbers in each line)

```
10
1000 1
1000 2
10
888 999
```

We can do this using sed and remembered patterns.
I am looking for the logic to get this done using awk/nawk and ksh commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best formatting, but `tr` does the job

```
$ tr '[a-z]' ' ' < file_containing_input
    10
 1000 1
 1000 2
    10
         888            999
```

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{ gsub(/[a-z]+/, " "); print }' file_containing_input
 10
 1000 1
 1000 2
 10
 888 999
```

And one in bash (now I need to stop...)

```
$ while read a; do echo ${a//[a-z]/ }; done < file_containing_input
10
1000 1
1000 2
10
888 999
```

Comment: Thanks for this.Here is a way to get the formatting using tr:               tr -s "[:alpha:]" "[ *]" <input_file

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a homework, as "we can do this using sed". Actually it is simple substitute command, that substitutes any amount of non numeric chars with space.

```
sed -r "s/[^0-9]+/\ /g" input_file
```

Comment: I dont think they give homework at my workplace .. .. I hope not atleast ..:). I know how to pull this one off in sed .. Can u suggest somethin using awk/ksh